# Python and OpenSSH

Tags: windows, python-2.7, putty, openssh

I feel like there is something fundamental I'm missing here, and because of that googling the error has been very difficult.

I've set up an SSH connection to my home computer using the instructions I found here:

https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_windows_openssh_server

I'm able to access ipython interactively by entering ipython but the prompt is not behaving at all like I expect. Please see the following interaction:

[image: IPython]

The session isn't immediately responsive and seems to be running the commands in some type of batch mode, and still not all of them. I don't receive any output until I exit the program. Running python and not ipython behaves similarly. I'm hoping to have a somewhat more standard interactive python experience, and have no idea how to go about debugging this.

Information on my system:
OS - Windows 10, both machines
SSH - OpenSSH set up through link above
Python - 2.7.11, Anaconda install 2.5.0
Remote access application - Putty

Thanks for any help-

Comment: Windows does not look production ready ...

Comment: can you explain what you mean by that Jakuje?